Can city codes be void-for-vagueness?

Accumulation of rubbish, trash, refuse, junk and other abandoned materials, metals, lumber or other things.

This is the Maumelle City Code - 38.2 (2)
When asked what needed to be changed to bring my yard into compliance I was never given an exhaustive list. Nor was accumulation defined (or a definition of abandoned).
Would (should) that law be considered void for vagueness? For instance - I have children who play in the yard and leave their toys in the yard. There is nothing abandoned about their toys as they're playing with them on a near-daily basis.

A city ordinance can be void for vagueness. This ordinance is not.
A city ordinance may be struck down as vague if it (1) "fails to establish standards for the police and public that are sufficient to guard against the arbitrary deprivation of liberty;" or (2) "fails to give the ordinary citizen adequate notice of what is forbidden and what is permitted." Chicago v. Morales, 527 U.S. 41, 42 (1999).
Although any ordinance could be enforced arbitrarily, there's nothing in here that suggests it encourages any kind of arbitrary enforcement that would create a problem under the first prong, and the ordinance seems to be clear enough to put ordinary citizens on notice of what they need to do.
The fact that children leave toys in the yard seems likely to be irrelevant. As you said, the property isn't abandoned, so it isn't violating the law.
Nor is it likely to be relevant that the ordinance doesn't define "accumulation" or "abandoned." Both of those are words with ordinary meanings, so the ordinary person already knows what they mean.

So in this particular case, it's not that the law is vague, it's just being applied incorrectly as "abandoned" means left and not continually in use?

@WayneWerner - Potentially, you have a factual disagreement with the code enforcement officer.  If the only issue is the childrens' toys, you could challenge the order before a judge and argue that the toys were neither junk nor trash and were not abandoned because they were played with regularly.  There may be some argument from the code enforcement about the state of repair of the toys or something of the sort.

@WayneWerner Since you haven't provided any details about what's in your yard other than children's toys, it's impossible to answer that. But we don't provide advice about individual legal situations here, just answer general or hypothetical questions.

@Barmar yeah, fair enough. But is it a correct/fair interpretation that abandoned is a key word in this code? Like, something that is actively in use can't be considered abandoned?

@WayneWerner Yes, that seems obvious. Also, it usually wouldn't be considered abandoned if it's on the owner's property. E.g. if you leave a car on the side of the road, you've abandoned it; if you put it up on blocks in your driveway, it's not.

I don't think the property needs to be abandoned. An accumulation of trash, refuse, or junk is a violation, whether it's abandoned or not.

@WayneWerner people sometimes think that a concept such as "junk" in the context of this ordinance must have a precise meaning.  Law frequently doesn't work this way because no matter how precisely you define it, someone is going to find a case where the definition isn't precise enough.  Furthermore, an overly precise definition might increase the likelihood of an unjust result.  For example, suppose "junk" is defined to include automobiles over 40 years old and then you leave your lovingly restored '57 Chevy parked outside one night.  You get the idea.

So the way it actually works is that the ordinance just says "junk," and then if someone claims that an object in your yard is junk, and if you disagree, then a judge decides.  They don't have to worry about coming up with a precise definition that will lead to a just result in every case; they only have to determine a just result in your case.  Law is full of such judgment calls; it is a feature of the system, not a bug.  This is why so many statutes use subjective words like "reasonable" and  "offensive."

@bdb484 but if the object in question isn't rubbish, trash, refuse, or junk then it would fall under this ordinance only if it is abandoned.  This is a good example of the judgment calls I was talking about in my previous comments: how long must an object be left alone to be considered abandoned?  It's going to depend on the context.  A paper coffee cup at a bus stop, probably a few minutes.  A bicycle in a bike rack in a public place, maybe several weeks.  A bicycle on someone's back porch, maybe never, or at least not until the entire property is considered abandoned.

That was my personal frustration - the code enforcement officer refused to give me a precise definition, simply handwaving and saying "oh the ladder is still in your yard, and there's some wooden reindeer" - but the ladder was in active use, at least once a week, and there's no law against yard/garden art

Clearly in my precise case I need to take photos next time, frequently, to prove that my children are really playing with their toys and I'm actually moving things - nothing is abandoned, despite accumulating at times
